# ConfigParser problem Python

Tags: python, configparser

I'm having problem to append to config file. Here's what I want to create;

```
[section1]
val1 = val2
val3 = val4
```

but when I run the following code I see `ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'section1'`

```
import ConfigParser

cfg = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
cfg.set("section1", "val1", "val2")

f = open("example.cfg", "a")
cfg.write(f)
```

If I add

```
if not cfg.has_section("section1"):
    cfg.add_section("section1")
```

and then, this is what I get;

```
[section1]
val1 = val2

[section1]
val3 = val4
```

Could someone point me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: No it works. I think I didn't make myself quite clear. I add the if statement before cfg.set(). I guess that's what made you confuse.

Answer (score 5):

I fleshed out the code you put up a bit.  Are you reading the existing file before checking for the section?  Also, you should be writing the whole file at once.  Don't append.

```
import ConfigParser

cfg = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read('example.cfg')

if not cfg.has_section('section1'):
    cfg.add_section('section1')

cfg.set('section1', 'val1', 'val2')
cfg.set('section1', 'val2', 'val3')

f = open('example.cfg', 'w')
cfg.write(f)
f.close()
```

Comment: I forgot to close the file. Thanks. Yes I'm reading an existing file. That's why I want to append new values to file. So should I read the existing file and write it again with new values?

Comment: If you write out the config file with your updates, all values you previously had will also exist, so yes.

Comment: Working fine with cfg file updation :)